# run go script after compile android

Tags: android, go

Go seems to be a well supported scripting language in Android. However, from the documentation it is clear that google wants you to include all go scripts in your Android project before compilation. Is there a way to avoid this?

Could I run a script created after compilation? Like downloading a script from a backend server and just run it?

Comment: Go is compiled language. Take into account and your question will be pretty much different.

Answer (score 2):

Go needs to be linked in the same manor as a C library would be. Go is also a compiled language, not a scripting language. To do as you suggest you would need to be downloading and executing an essentially arbitrary executable which as far as I am aware is not supported.

One possible avenue, would be downloading and dynamically linking the Go library you create. However I am not sure if that is actually achievable.